# Python 3 loop acting on arrays gives error message unless 'pointless' a print statement is added

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Basically I run a for loop and get an error message and it does not run, if I run the same for loop with a print statement within it the code seems to work correctly.

This is my code, In this code I am primarily acting on one array **magnitude_differences** of shape (68, 4461, 2) to create a new array corrections. The array **reference_star_magnitudes** is of shape (4461, 68, 2) I am just using this to slightly future proof the code.

```
corrections = [] 
for i,_ in enumerate(reference_star_magnitudes):
    corrections.append( np.mean([ float(row[i].T[0]) 
                        for row in magnitude_differences 
                        if float(row[i].T[0]) < 2. ]) ) 
corrections = np.array(corrections)
```

Gives the error message:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:59: 
 warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:70: 
 ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

This code with the print statement appears to run perfectly.

```
corrections = [] 
for i,_ in enumerate(reference_star_magnitudes):
    print('nothing') 
    corrections.append( np.mean([ float(row[i].T[0]) 
                        for row in magnitude_differences 
                        if float(row[i].T[0]) < 2. ]) ) 
corrections = np.array(corrections)
```

Comment: A `print` statement cannot cause this effect. There is some other difference in the code you're running.

Comment: There is no difference at all, I'm not sure if there is a way I can prove this to you.

Comment: The warning will probably only show up the first time you run it in a session. Are you running your `print("nothing")` version after you run the first one without?

Comment: Thanks I realised what's happened now, the print statement stops the error message from running that's all. I thought the code was not running without the print statement but it is. Apologies for the dum question but you helped me answer it!

Comment: under what conditions does the absence of `print()` cause an error and trace to be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

The print statement stops the error message from running that's all. I thought the code was not running without the print statement but it is. Apologies for the dum late night question but you helped me answer it!